# Submit user input by click AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, input, user-input

I am just starting my adventure with coding in AS3.
 I would love to learn how to submit my input by clicking a button and check if it is same as my "password" number. Then, display the message in the dynamic field about the results. 
I have written some code and it does not show any errors, but - as you may guess - it does not work either.

I thought that using the command 
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
and then creating a simple if... else statement is enough, but somehow it does not work.

Would you kindly take a look at my code and point the mistake which has lead to my misery?

here is the code:

```
    private var Input:Object;
    private var Output:Object;
    private var yournr:String;
    public function Tehtava25a()
    {
        var Input:TextField = new TextField();
        var Output:TextField = new TextField();
        var initialtxt:String = "Give me the password";

        Input.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
        Input.border = true;
        Input.width = 200;
        Input.height = 200;
        Input.backgroundColor=0xFFFF99;
        Input.background =true;
        Input.borderColor=0x006666;
        addChild(Input);

        Output.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
        Output.text=  initialtxt;
        Output.background = true;
        Output.border = true;
        Output.backgroundColor=0xFFFF99;
        Output.background =true;
        Output.borderColor=0x006666;
        Output.width = 200;
        Output.height = 200;
        Output.x = 200;
        addChild(Output);   
        var button:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
        button.x = 250;
        button.y = 250;

        button.upState = createCircle( 0x00FF00, 15 );
        button.overState = createCircle( 0xFFFFFF, 16 );
        button.downState = createCircle( 0xCCCCCC, 15 );
        addChild( button );
        button.hitTestState = createCircle( 0x000000, 50 );

        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick , false, 0, true);


    }

    private function createCircle(param0:Number, param1:int):DisplayObject
    {var circle:Shape = new Shape(  );
        circle.graphics.lineStyle( 1, 0x000000 );
        circle.graphics.beginFill( 0xFF794B );
        circle.graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 30 );
        circle.graphics.endFill(  );
        return circle;
    }

    protected function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {var yournr:String = Input.text;
    var mynr:String = "1234";
        if (yournr == mynr){
            Output.appendText = "the number is correct"}
        else { Output.appendText = "try again";
        }
    }   
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TextFiels.appendText(...) is a method, not a property. You use it as the following:

```
protected function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var yournr:String = Input.text;
    var mynr:String = "1234";

    if (yournr == mynr)
    {
        Output.appendText("the number is correct");
    }
    else
    {
        Output.appendText("try again");
    }
}
```

If you does not want to append text but rather to place given text into the text field you need to assign its .text property:

```
protected function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var yournr:String = Input.text;
    var mynr:String = "1234";

    if (yournr == mynr)
    {
        Output.text = "the number is correct";
    }
    else
    {
        Output.text = "try again";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a mixup of local properties you have at the top of your code

```
private var Input:Object;
private var Output:Object;
```

and local variables in your class constructor

```
var Input:TextField = new TextField();
var Output:TextField = new TextField();
```

When you declare something in a method (in your case the class constructor) with a "var" it will be accessible only in this method but not by other methods. So you create the textfields in your constructor but the handleClick is working with the variables that you have declared at the top of your code (with private var ...).

In other words the beginning of your code should look like this:

```
 private var Input:TextField;
 private var Output:TextField;
 private var yournr:String;

 public function Tehtava25a()
 {
     //this will refer to the variables above and not local ones
     Input = new TextField();
     Output = new TextField();
```

And it is a bad practice to start the variables with an uppercase letter, in the Adobe common practices the variables are camelcase and start with a lowercase letter and the classes start with an uppercase letter. Usually it's a good practice to name the variables something like outputTextField so you instantly see in the code what is what :)

Comment: I used your suggestions and it worked! Indeed, variables were the issue - I have change them accordingly to your suggestion and it worked perfectly. I also used changed appendText into just .text and it displays smothly and beautifully! Oh, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark my answer as the correct one ;)